# DOMException for when trying to add a node

Tags: java, dom

there are two functions for adding nodes to a list of nodes:

```
class mynodeList implements NodeList {  


    Node root ;
    int length = 0;

    public mynodeList() {}   
    public Node addFirstNode(Node node)
    {
        root=node;
        length++;
        return root;

    }
    public void addNode(Node node) {  
     //  System.out.println(root.getClass());
         root.appendChild(node);   
        length++;   
    } 
}
```

I made a function to add first node  then for the rest, it uses the second one. but when it goes to `appendChild(node);` giving me an `DOMException` which says : `attempt for adding a node to a place which is not possible.`
what is wrong with my code?
where should it be if not a child of first node!?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense. It adds the second node as a child of the first. That's not my idea of a node list. A NodeList is supposed to maintain a list of siblings. It is also *not* supposed to have any side-effects on those siblings.

Comment: @user1064929 The fact that it isn't a nodelist *is* the problem. It's no good just saying 'so what?' about that. You need a list and you don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I hope this will answer your question :

> The NodeList interface provides the abstraction of an ordered
>   collection of nodes

What oracle ([Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html)) mean is that you can use whatever collection you want, it's just to create some abstraction. So you could just try the following code (I couldn't test it, i don't have you Node implementation), and if you want something more than collections, I suggest you to take a look [there](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/jakarta-jmeter-2.0.1/src/htmlparser/org/htmlparser/util/NodeList.java.shtml).

```
public class NodeList implements org.w3c.dom.NodeList{

    List<Node> childs;

    public NodeList() {
        childs = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }   

    public void addNode(Node node) {  
        childs.add(node);
    }

    @Override
    public Node item(int i) {
        return childs.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getLength() {
        return childs.size();
    }  
}
```